# Monochrome image with CSS (not just BW)

Tags: css

I am trying to process an image with CSS to get it as a monochrome (let's say "blue-white". I know how to desaturate image with CSS:

```
.image img
{
filter: gray;
filter: grayscale(1);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
}
```

But I'd like to get it black/white with bluish (redish, yellowish...) tint.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Add a manual filter on top of the image with `background-color: ... ;` in **rgba**.
Add `grayscale` and `opacity` filters to the image. Adjust opacity to get the required clarity.

### Red

```css
#cover, img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#cover {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    top: -300px;
}
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) opacity(0.8) ;
    filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.masala.com/sites/default/files/images/2013/12/03/colours.jpg" />
<div id="cover"></div>
```

### Yellow

```css
#cover, img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#cover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    top: -300px;
}
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) opacity(0.8) ;
    filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.masala.com/sites/default/files/images/2013/12/03/colours.jpg" />
<div id="cover"></div>
```

### Blue

```css
#cover, img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#cover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    top: -300px;
}
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) opacity(0.8) ;
    filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.masala.com/sites/default/files/images/2013/12/03/colours.jpg" />
<div id="cover"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like here is the way to make it happen. "a bit" tricky but... looks like it does what I am after.

```
    .stuff {
   background-blend-mode: luminosity;
    background: url(ms_001.jpg) no-repeat center hsl(200,50%,50%);
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66n0p5sw/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice solution using an `::after` pseudo-element. Note: I had to wrap the `img` within a `span` because `img` elements *still* don't support them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
span {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span><img src="https://ykloh2l68ra38u6ir1pvy71k-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/ABSSS2_Keyart_roviocom-555x312.1875-c-center.jpg" /></span>
```